# Zombie account was somehow created, and I am unable to submit a merge form (profiles already linked)

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, user-accounts, merge-accounts

Update 1: scifi mod tells me a CM contacted me this morning, I haven't received any e-mail (I checked the spam too). Not sure if it's related.

Update 2: got a reply for the latest form submitted from here, it's currently being looked into by the developer team.

[image]

Not-dupe to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist): I *filled the merge-request form* but it said they are already merged, form cannot be sent.

[image]
(Drop down view.)

URL's of accounts in questions:

A) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80704/
B) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80756/ (now shows same user name as A, but different URL, earlier it had my G+ pic and name!)

[image]
(View from B.)

I have no idea how B) was created, I filled the merge-request form but it said they are already merged.

#### Issues being faced:

1. <strike>Reputation changes for A don't show in the notification</strike>
2. I can't change profile settings for A (check below screen)
3. I have no access to settings of B, **so I can't submit delete request**
4. I can't access scifi-meta from A (needs logging-in despite being logged-in)
5. No association bonus for A/B

[image]
(Point 2. above, I tried the password reset, no effect. Right now I have only one log-in method.)

Earlier: account B had a hash-code kind of name, then it changed to my G+ name and picture, I was able to change that from my main parent account by saving settings to all.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

P.S. During scifi account creation, an error message appeared that said SE was notified of the error.

Comment: check added screencap, form won't go through, not a dupe, thanks

Comment: Just use the [contact form](/contact), choose "other" and explain what's going on. Not much anyone here can do about it.

Comment: Can you access both accounts? If so, just delete the account with 1 rep, you should have a delete option in your profile somewhere. (It won't be instant, wait for a day or something like that after clicking it)

Comment: @ShadowWizard can't access B at all, as I wrote.

Comment: So I'm afraid only a developer can help, submit a form as @Cai suggested and wait. Can't see any real harm done here so far.

Comment: @Cai I did submit an *Other* form but I haven't received the confirmation e-mail, it's been many hours still no e-mail.

Comment: @zm3 there is not automatic confirmation email in Stack Exchange. Average wait time from what I can tell is about two days for non urgent things. (keep in mind that team of 2-3 people handle thousands of requests per day.)

Comment: Fair enough, but as I said, not much anyone here can do other than direct you to the contact form

Comment: @Cai understood, will try contact form from meta, not from scifi, thanks

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh I thought there was an e-mail, it says you'll receive an e-mail shortly, and I have before on previous submissions, thanks for the help though. I'll wait and see.

Comment: @zm3 true, but it's not automatic. It's sent only when SE employee gets the ticket and starts working on it.

Comment: @Elephant I have them hidden, the option is under profile settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without spending too much time digging into what happened here... it looks like you may have created what we call an "unregistered" account somehow - that is, an account without login credentials, identified only by a cookie. Then... I really have no idea what happened.

Long story short, though, I fixed up your profiles, so everything should be in the same spot again. Sorry about all the hassle. Let me know if you still see any issues.

Comment: All fixed, much appreciated :)